# Slow https requests after sudden spike in mysql queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, ssl, https

I have wordpress website running in a VPS server and is handling about 150 mysql queries / second.

Ocassionaly when we notice a spike in traffic to about 200 mysql queries a second the https requests to the site is extremely slow.

The site loads decently with http but with https it takes 20+ seconds.

Gradually over a period of an hour after the spike, the load times get better and then it gets back to normal again.

There server load and memory looks fine. There is only a spike in mysql queries, firewall traffic and eth0 requests. There are no mysql slow queries

[image: Munin server graphs for reference]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Smells like a DOS attack from 4am-6am.

Comment: What is the value of `long_query_time`? Set is significantly lower so you can catch some of the "slow queries". There may be a spike in certain "slow queries" during your spike.

Comment: currently it is 10 seconds, I will decrease this and see if it catches more. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in "disk latency" and "disk utilization" charts.

MySQL works well under small loads, when it can cache all data it needs. But when your results or queries get too big, or you request too many of them, it will start doing many disk I/O operations. This enables you to handle huge loads and very big data, but in the moment you exceed your MySQL allocated memory, you will need to read and write everything to disk.

This would not be so bad if you ran on a local SSD drive. But from the device name I see that you are running on an EBS volume, which is not a real hard drive. It is networked drive, so all the traffic overloads your network connection.

You have several options:

1.) install `mysqltuner`, let the server operate for some time and then run it and see what it suggest. My guess is, that it will suggest you to increase your MySQL memory pool, decrease number of parallel connections or restructure your queries.

2.) use EC2 instance type with actual local storage (e.g. m3 or r3) and write to local SSD. You can do RAID on several SSD drives to make it even faster.

3.) use EBS optimized instance (dedicated EBS network bandwidth) and correct volume type (some EBS volume types have I/O credits, similar to CPU credits for t-type instances, and when you run of those, your operations will slow down to crawl).

Comment: Thank for the options grepe, makes sense now why the network is slowing down. I have been digging into this matter more today. The whole database is only about 40mb. There is 8gb ram on the server. I think there is some optimization to do. I just found out all the tables are myisam type so I am looking at the key_buffer_size settings. I need to convert them to innodb but I am unsure if I can do this on the fly safely.

Comment: MySQL memory pool is tricky. It allocates a fixed amount of memory for every parallel connection, so when you make too many of those, you will run out of memory even if your actual data is small and you have lots of RAM. It all depends on your configuration.

Comment: [_Memory tips_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-memory-allocation/) for MyISAM and InnoDB.  The key_buffer is for indexes only.  [_Conversion to InnoDB tips_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/)  The buffer_pool is for both data and indexes.